# Complete values are not writing to the file using Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

My idea is to write some large number of bits to a file (almost 64*4800 bits). It is writing but not all the bits.

The console output looks like

> [1. 1. 0. ... 1. 0. 1.]

If I decrement the number of bits to be saved then it will work.

I will paste my code here. This code is sampling the analog to digital

```
y= function(x) #  Inside this function I am generating binary values and stored to y
################  y is in numpy.ndarray form
################  x is a sine wave

f=open('filename.txt',"w+")
f.write(str(y))  #we have to convert the numpy.ndarray to str. 
f.close()
```

when I open my `filename.txt` file it is showing the binary values as

> [1. 1. 0. ... 1. 0. 1.]

which is same as in the console.

Please help me to resolve this issue. I need all the bits (64*4800) to be saved inside the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try converting your numpy array to a list first:

```
y = function(x) #  Inside this function I am generating binary values and stored to y
################  y is in numpy.ndarray form
################  x is a sine wave
y_list = y.tolist()  # Convert to python list
# use the with context manager and you don't need to call .close() explicitly
with open('filename.txt',"w+") as f:
    f.write(str(y_list))  #we have to convert the numpy.ndarray to a list and then  to str(y_list) which will write the entire bits.
```

Comment: I changed the code as you mentioned . But still the output is same. :(

Comment: Can I see the code for function(x) ? I suspect it's actually returning what you output to the file and that the flaw is there.

Comment: I have changed the f.write(str(y)) to  f.write(str(y_list)). We were not passing the converted list. That was the issue. I edited that and accepted your answer. Thanks